Is it really necessary to go to all this trouble to split division algebras?
Let $D$ be a finite-dimensional central simple algebra over a field $K$. $D$ is said to split over a field extension $L/K$ if we have $D_L \cong D \otimes_K L \cong M_n(L)$ for some $n$. In a few places (e.g. the Stacks Project) people seem to go to a lot of trouble to prove that $D$ always splits over a finite separable extension; one first shows that $D$ always splits over a maximal subfield of $D$ (this argument is nice), then that such a subfield can be chosen to be separable (this argument is a little fiddly).
The point of this, as far as I can tell, is to show the Brauer group $\text{Br}(K)$ can be computed as a filtered colimit of relative Brauer groups $\text{Br}(L/K)$ as $L$ runs over finite separable extensions of $K$.
However, it seems to me like we can prove that $D$ always splits over a finite separable extension via a general spreading out argument, without knowing anything about the subfields of $D$ at all, as follows:

First show that the extension of scalars $D_L$ remains a finite central simple algebra over $L$.

Next, the only finite central simple algebras over a separably closed field are matrix algebras, so $D$ splits over the separable closure $K^s$ at worst, meaning we have an isomorphism $D_{K^s} \cong M_n(K^s)$.

Now the spreading out argument: this isomorphism and its inverse, when expressed as matrices with respect to any basis of $D$ and the standard matrix basis of $M_n$, only involve finitely many elements of $K^s$, so $D$ in fact splits over the subfield generated by these elements, which is a finite separable extension of $K^s$.


Does this argument work? If so, why go to all the trouble that the usual line of argument goes to? I admit you do learn more from the usual line of argument but I'm surprised I haven't seen the spreading out argument anywhere yet.

Okay, I think I see what the issue is. It's the second step:


Next, the only finite central simple algebras over a separably closed field are matrix algebras, so $D$ splits over the separable closure $K^s$ at worst, meaning we have an isomorphism $D_{K^s} \cong M_n(K^s)$.


This is clear for the algebraic closure (we just need to show that there are no nontrivial finite-dimensional division algebras over $\overline{K}$ which is standard); however, to prove this result for the separable closure we need to rule out the possibility that there is a finite central division algebra $D$ over $K^s$ all of whose elements are purely inseparable over $K^s$. This can be done but the argument is exactly the argument used by the Stacks project to show that we can find a separable maximal subfield so we haven't actually avoided that argument. And also, now that I've taken a second look at it it's a pretty nice argument anyway!

If you want to recover your nice argument, I think you can reason in step 2 by using the fact that every smooth scheme over a field $F$ has a point over $F_{sep}$. In this way, one can observe that every torsor of a smooth group scheme over $Spec(F)$ is split over $F_{sep}$. Since CSAs of degree $n$ over $F$ are the same as $PGL_{n}$-torsors over $Spec(F)$, we're done, assuming I haven't made any silly mistakes (I am pretty rusty). Of course, this is much higher tech than the stacks project argument, so it's probably kind of missing the point. :)

Incidentally, I quite like the maximal subfields approach. Besides the filtered colimit benefit, it also gives you explicit data about degrees of splitting fields, which your approach does not seem to. Using this, you can get some nice basic results about multiplicative and division relations between index, degree, and degrees of maximal subfields, among other things. You can also use this to show that cyclic algebras corresponding to a Galois extension $L/F$ are split by $L$, and I don't know that this is obvious without the basics of maximal subfields.

@Alex: yes, I've spent some time recently working through the details and maximal subfields are great, no argument there!
